# SQL commands with or without table?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I am a beginner in MySQL. I find some commands have the word table before the table name while some do not. Why is it so?

With *table*:

```
CREATE TABLE <table name>

ALTER TABLE <table name>

DROP TABLE <table name>
```

Without *table*:

```
DESC <table name>

INSERT INTO <table name>

UPDATE  <table name>
```

Comment: For example, look at how many things you can do with a CREATE and compare that with how many things you can do with an INSERT. Thats why [Create](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) Ditto ALTER etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DML commands like `insert` or `update` only apply to tables, so it the SQL language designers probably didn't see a point in specifying the word "table" there.

On the other hand, DDL commands likes `create`, `alter` or `drop` could apply to several types of objects such as tables (which you mentioned), views, indexes, etc., each of which has their own properties and their own syntax.

Comment: Is this also the reason behind the syntaxes `CREATE DATABASE <name>` and `USE <name>`?

Comment: @Shub yup, same reasoning